# Macbook Broadcom 4331 was working, now enable wifi isn't an option. (14.04)

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I've tried a few different fixes from here and a couple other places and I just can't get the wifi to show up at all anymore. It was working (not good, it was slow and would frequently drop), something was changed and now enable wifi doesn't show up.

I ran the wireless script and this is what I got.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11339101/

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is missing the firware, with an internet connection do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

That wll install the required firmware.
Reboot

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to internet by wire and install the driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you previously tried to install other drivers, then also run

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```